# How to use Tensorflow C library in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to run the Tensorflow C library here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c

When extracting the file "libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-1.13.1"
For some reason, there is no .lib file included, there is only a "tensorflow.dll"

How do I use this library without the .lib file? / Where do I get the .lib file from?

Comment: It doesn't come with a lib file. You can either build from source, or use the `dumpbin` and `lib` command-line tools to build a lib file from the dll for the target platform, either x64 or x86

Comment: See [TensorFlow C library now available for Windows?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10817) for some discussion about this with possibly useful links.